# Tkinter or Python does and does not recognize file location

Tags: python, file, tkinter, label, gif

Hey guys I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Deaven And Teigan/Documents/Python Projects/Tkinter Tut.py", line 16, in <module>
    background_label = Label(image=b'C:\Users\Deaven And Teigan\Documents\Python Projects\Teigan.gif')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2596, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2075, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "C:\Users\Deaven And Teigan\Documents\Python Projects\Teigan.gif" doesn't exist
```

Problem is the file location from the properties menu is

C:\Users\Deaven And Teigan\Documents\Python Projects

The File name is

Teigan

The file type is .gif

Python knows where it is though, I made that pathway by selecting from a pop-up list inside the editor that comes from the new window selection in IDLE.

This is not the only time I have chosen a file from the pop up menu and python doesn't recognize it.

What could be wrong?

Comment: So you're saying the file loads no problem from another location?

Answer (score 3):

Take a closer look at the error message. It isn't telling you the *file* doesn't exist, it is telling you that an *image* with that name doesn't exist. In this context, *image* refers to a Tkinter image object.

```
background_label = Label(image=b'C:\Users\Deaven And Teigan\Documents\Python Projects\Teigan.gif')
```

The value given to the `image` attribute is not a path, it should be a `PhotoImage` or `BitmapImage` or a compatible object.

```
image = PhotoImage(file='C:\Users\Deaven And Teigan\Documents\Python Projects\Teigan.gif')
background_label = Label(parent, image=photo)
background_label.image = image
```

[`background_label.image = image`](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)